# How to disable microphone once speech recognition is completed?

Tags: html, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have recently implemented a feature of speech recognition using HTML5 speech API which can be integrated with Google Chrome.

The problem I'm facing is how should I disable the microphone once the speech is completed?

[image]

The recording sign should not be there once speech is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.stop()` method of `MediaStreamTrack`, and `.removeTrack()` with `MediaStreamTrack` as parameter, which stops the `MediaStreamTrack` and sets the `MediaStream` to `.active` property to `false`

```
  <body>
    <button>click</button>
   <script>
     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
     .then(stream => {
       const track =  stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
       console.log(track, track.readyState, stream, stream.active);
       track.onended = e => {
         console.log(e.type, track.readyState)
       }
       stream.oninactive = e => {
         console.log(e.type, stream.active)
       }
       document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
         track.stop();
         stream.removeTrack(track);
       }
     })
   </script>
  </body>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/eqbZAI9SYwGTxEdgw92D?p=preview